# OpenDNS Web Content Filtering

Tags: dns, parental-controls, opendns

I'm trying to block certain websites using OpenDNS but running into issues.

I have successfully managed to get it to block general adult websites, but there are a few other websites I'd like to block too.

As a test, I'm trying to get it to block Gumtree, and have added it to my 'Always block' list. But the website is still visible for me.

At one point it was briefly working, in the sense that I tried visiting Gumtree and it was blocked. But I then unblocked a different website that was previously on the list, and then Gumtree became visible again.

It's like I somehow broke everything just by unblocking the other website.

See my settings in the below screengrab:

[image: screengrab of OpenDNS settings]

Comment: Just to make sure: You _did_ flush the DNS cache after every (failed) attempt?

Comment: I've just tried again now with `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` on my Mac but it's still not working